# Concatenate a string onto the end of a pointer variable

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-concatenation

fairly new to C. Having trouble with a certain function. The function is suppose to concatenate a str onto the end of *destp. First extends *destp to be long enough to hold the contents of both strings, by calling kstrextend(). Then copies the contents of src into the dest.

This is my current code right now, only because it compiles. I want to change so I can call my kstrextend() function which reallocates the memory.
Also I'm running test cases and I'm having a core dump after it ask for "kstrcat of two empty kstrings."

```
    void kstrcat(kstring *destp, kstring src)
    {
        int lenDest = destp->length;
        //int lenSrc = src.length;

       destp = realloc(destp,lenDest*sizeof(char));

       int i = 0;

       while(src.data[i] != '\0')
       {
           destp->data[i+lenDest+1] = src.data[i];
       }
       destp->data[i+lenDest+1] = '\0';
   }
```

Also here is my kstrextend function in case of reference or anything I might need to change.

```
    void kstrextend(kstring *strp, size_t nbytes)
    {
        char *data1;
        int len=strp->length;
        if(len < nbytes)
        {
            //allocate a new array with larger size
            data1 = realloc(strp->data, nbytes);
            if(data1 == NULL)
            {
                abort();
            }
            strp->data = data1;
            strp->length = nbytes;
            //remaining space of new array is filled with '\0'
            for (int i = len; i < nbytes; i++)
            {
                strp->data[i] = '\0';
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: 1) C does not have a string type. 2) You cannot append a `char []` to a pointer - very different types! 3) You can, however append a `char []` to what a `char`-pointer **points to**, provided there is enough space. But `*(char *)` is a `char`, not a `char []`.

Comment: @Barmar kstring is my struct type.

Comment: `while(src.data[i] != '\0')`. Looks like an infinete loop for all non-empty strings in `src`. `i` is never changed so the same byte is being checked over and over again. Also, you really need to provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ClaytonTM9 Okay, so what is it?

Comment: This does not work:  `void kstrcat(kstring *destp, kstring src) ... destp = realloc(destp,lenDest*sizeof(char));`  That changes the value of `destp` (and leaks the old value if the `realloc()` fails...), but it will not change the `kstring *` value held by the code that calls `kstrcat()`.  Since that value is no longer valid, you get a core dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add 1 to the index when assigning to the destination string. That's leaving the null byte that ended the destination string in it, instead of overwriting it with the first byte of the source.

Also, you forgot to increment `i` in your loop.

```
void kstrcat(kstring *destp, kstring src)
{
    int lenDest = destp->length;
    int lenSrc = src.length;

    kstrextend(destp, lenDest + lenSrc);

    int i = 0;
    while(src.data[i] != '\0')
    {
        destp->data[i+lenDest] = src.data[i];
        i++;
    }
    destp->data[i+lenDest] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Hate to bring up an old topic, but when I run a memory check I get 3 errors all as a result from line `while(scrc.data[i] != '\0'` Could you help with figuring out why i'm getting memory errors?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that when you initially create your `kstring`s, you're not adding an extra byte to the allocations for the null terminators.

Comment: I figured out my problem. Instead of `while(src.data[i] != '\0'` I used a for loop `for(int i = 0 ; i < src.length; i++)` and it worked out perfectly.

Comment: They should be the same, because `kstrextend` initializes all the new entries with 0.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you would concatenate two strings

```
char *strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *pend;

    /* make pend point to end of dest */
    for (pend = dest; *pend; ++pend)
        ;

    /* copy src to pend. Assume dest has enough space */
    while (*pend++ = *src++)
        ;

    /* null terminate dest */
    *pend = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: How does this help with his implementation of strings using a structure with `length` and `data`.

Comment: @Barmar by showing the base algorithm, the OP can use this code to implement it using a structure containing `length` and `data`.

Comment: This code is quite dangerous, because it assumes that dest is already reallocated to hold the total length.
Furthermore,  there is a dereference operator missing in the first for loop

     for (pend = dest; *pend; ++pend)

and

Comment: @StefanW The caller should pass a valid string and do the bounds checking himself.